# R base plot, combine mirrored right triangles

Tags: r, plot, radix

I am trying to build some figures comprised to 2 right triangles arranged in a mirror-image of each other. The final plots will have unique data set, but for now I am plotting the same data. I am more familiar with (maybe spoiled by) ggplot, but I've found that it's much easier to shift the axis locations in base R. If anyone knows how to replicate these right-triangle plots in ggplot I would take that answer!

I'm having trouble with adjusting the spacing and layout. I'm not as familiar with base R plotting, sorry if these are kinda of basic.

[image]

Specifically I'd like to:

- move the triangles closer together
- make it so the labels are visible (and use a top label that isn't `**main**`)
- make the diagonal line flush with the axes
- make the 'legs' of the triangles of equal length

  ```
  library(cowplot)
  my.data <- data.frame( my.x = c(.2,.4,.6, .1), my.y = c(.3, .5, .7, .9) )

     top.triangle <- function(){
    plot( my.y ~ my.x, data =  my.data, 
  axes = FALSE, ylab = 'Position.2', xlab = NA, main='Position.1',
  xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1),  xaxt="n", yaxt="n" )
    axis(side = 2, las = 1, pos=0)
    axis(side = 3, las = 1, pos=1)
    abline(coef = c(0,1))
     }

  bottom.triangle <- function() {
    plot( my.x ~ my.y, data = my.data , 
      axes = FALSE, xlab = 'Position.2', ylab = 'Position.1', xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1),  xaxt="n", yaxt="n" )
    axis(side = 1, las = 1, pos=0)
    axis(4, las = 1, pos=1) #flip label to right side
    abline(coef = c(0,1))}

  plot_grid(top.triangle, bottom.triangle, rel_widths = c(.5,.5))
  ```

Thanks!

Comment: how do you get this image? cowplot doesn't work with base graphics. how close should they be? if you set the `par(mar = )` to 0, they would still not be so close. use `segments(0, 0, 1, 1)` instead of `abline` and `par(mfrow = c(1, 2))` or `layout` instead of `cowplot` the legs depend on your device dimensions and margins

Comment: If you want the triangles close together, I think you will have better luck drawing on a single plot than two separate plots.

Comment: what's wrong with `with(my.data, {
  plot(c(my.x, my.y), c(my.y, my.x), asp = 1); 
  segments(0, 0, 1, 1); 
  abline(v = 0:1, h = 0:1)
})
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@GregorThomas* suggested, it's probably better to draw a single plot. For this, a `transform`ed additional data frame is needed, that shifts the values by an distance `x.dist`.

```
my.data <- data.frame(my.x=c(.2, .4, .6, .1), my.y=c(.3, .5, .7, .9))
x.dist <- .5
my.data.2 <- transform(my.data, my.y=my.y + x.dist)
```

Now I've modified your functions substantially, I suggest to figure out line by line which arguments I've used. Importantly I use `xpd=TRUE` to be able to plot beyond the plot region. With `par` I expand the `mar`gins a little. I use `mtext` together with `axis` to get tickmarks and labels. To make diagonal line flush with the axes I used `lines` instead of `abline`. The bottom.triangle2 now uses `points` rather than `plot`, because `plot` has no `add=TRUE` argument. And I use `asp=1` in `top.triangle2` to make equilateral triangles.

```
top.triangle2 <- function() {
  plot(my.y ~ my.x, data= my.data, axes=FALSE, ylab='', xlab="", 
       main='', xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", asp=1)
  mtext("Here could be your title", 3, 5, font=2, cex=1.3, adj=.95)
  mtext("Position.2", 2, .75)
  mtext("Position.1", 3, 2)
  axis(side=2, las=1, pos=0)
  axis(side=3, las=1, pos=1)
  lines(0:1, 0:1)
}

bottom.triangle2 <- function() {
  points(my.x ~ my.y, data=my.data.2, xpd=TRUE)
  mtext("Position.2", 1, 1.5, at=mean(par()$usr[1:2]) + x.dist)
  mtext("Position.1", 4, 3, padj=par()$usr[1] + 10)
  x.at <- axisTicks(par()$usr[1:2], 0) + x.dist
  axis(side=1, las=1, pos=0, at=x.at, 
       labels=F, xpd=TRUE)
  mtext(seq(0, 1, .2), 1, 0, at=x.at)
  axis(4, las=1, pos=1 + x.dist)
  lines(0:1 + x.dist, 0:1, xpd=TRUE)
}
```

I use `png` to get reproducible output.

```
png("myplot.png", width=650, height=500)
op <- par(mar=c(3, 4, 8, 12) + 0.1, oma=c(2, 0, 0, 2))
top.triangle2()
bottom.triangle2()
par(op)
dev.off()
```

## Result

[image]

Maybe you figure out on your own how to avoid that much hard coding.

Comment: Awesome!! That looks so much nicer! Thanks for stepping through and explaining your edits.

Comment: do you have advice for arranging multiple version of these plots in an Rmd document?

Comment: @user1757654 It's probably easier to arrange the `png`s of these plots, i.e. creating them in an invisible chunk, and use something like [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html) to arrange them.

Comment: I've been using the png+cowplot, but I'm having issues adjusting the text size and image resolution. I'm trying to make some 3x3 grid of these but my attempts are all fuzzy.